# Install TypeScript Compiler with NuGet Package Manager in Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2013, nuget-package

I had previously installed TypeScript for VS 2013 from:

https://www.typescriptlang.org/#download-links

Now, this option is not available anymore. I uninstalled it, because I wanted to use NuGet Package Manager to install the TypeScript Compiler locally to my project, for portability.  Moving to another PC should not require a separate TypeScript installation.

[image]

When I clicked Install, nothing happened. Maybe it was installed? There was no indication.

So, I also tried to install it from NuGet Package Manager Console, and it says it was installed successfully:

[image]

**Question 1: How can I see where it was installed?**

- The packages.config has no reference to TypeScript.
- The packages folder also doesn't contain any TypeScript packages.
- When I try to build the project, I get an error:

  > Error   11  The specified task executable "tsc.exe" could not be run.
  >   Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
  >   SDKs\TypeScript\1.8'.   BGIS.Reports.Web

**Question 2: What am I doing wrong? How can I fix the issue?**

Comment: I recommend [Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild/) instead. See [Compiler Options in MSBuild](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options-in-msbuild.html) and [MSBuild csproj settings](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/integrating-with-build-tools.html#msbuild). This is the MS recommended approach to getting it to work with msbuild.

Comment: I have just installed it (after I removed prev TypeScript installation), but when I try to build a project I get an error: The "JsxPreserve" parameter is not supported by the "VsTsc" task. Verify the parameter exists on the task, and it is a settable public instance property. BGIS.Reports.Web

Answer (score 1):

With old version of Typescript installed from nugget package, VS used the path to know which version of typescript it should use to compile.

You just need to set the change in Path environment variable the TypeScript location folder :

[image]

Comment: How to get to this window?